# Mathematical Explanation of an Integration by Parts Formula

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, area

I understand that the formula $uv - \int vdu$ can be utilized to integrate expressions such as $$ \int_{0}^7 7x\sqrt[3]{x+1}dx $$ $$= 1209/4$$ Nonetheless, I am not aware of the mathematical reasoning behind this formula; why does it work and when is it ideal to use it? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have you read the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts)? Perhaps you should read it carefully first. If you have more specific questions after that, you can always ask them here.

Comment: Integration by parts is the product rule in reverse. Start with the $(fg)' = f'g + f g'$, then integrate both sides from $a$ to $b$, and you get the integration by parts formula.

Answer (score 1):

It's the antiderivative equivalent of the product rule.

The Product Rule: $\frac{d}{dx}(fg) = f'g + fg'$

Thus, $fg = \int(f'g + fg')dx = \int(f'g)dx + \int(fg')dx$

From this, one can deduce that $\int(fg')dx = fg - \int(f'g)dx$

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).